# How can I convert a bitstring to the binary form in Julia

Tags: binary, julia, representation, bitstring

I am using bitstring to perform an xor operation on the ith bit of a string:

```
string = bitstring(string ⊻ 1 <<i)
```

However the result will be a string, so I cannot continue with other i.

So I want to know how do I convert a bitstring (of the form “000000000000000000000001001”) to (0b1001)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`parse`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.parse) to create an integer from the string, and then use [`string`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.string) (alt. [`bitstring`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.bitstring))to go the other way. Examples:

```
julia> str = "000000000000000000000001001";

julia> x = parse(UInt, str; base=2) # parse as UInt from input in base 2
0x0000000000000009

julia> x == 0b1001
true

julia> string(x; base=2) # stringify in base 2
"1001"

julia> bitstring(x) # stringify as bits (64 bits since UInt64 is 64 bits)
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001"
```

Comment: would it still work if I do bitstring(x \xor 01001)?

Comment: `bitstring` is an alternative to `string(x; base=2)` if that is what you are asking, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `bitstring`. You can either do the math with a `BitVector` or just a `UInt`. No reason to bring a `String` into it.